# how to add custom price in variable product woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Need to change the price range (from low price to high price) to custom price 
and user can't add product to cart without select option first 
[their is a photo of product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SFs2.png)

Answer (score -1):

to add a variable product follow the bellow steps

1. go products -- > attributes then add attributes (ex : tomato category )
2. then find Configure terms column under new attribute -- > then set terms (Ex: local tomatoes , exported tomatoes)
3. then go to products --> add new product --> select variable product as the product type
4. then go to attributes under that new product  -- > select the attribute you already created.  check **Used for variations** option and save that attribute
5. then go to variation tab and set variation after that you can set custom prize under each variation types